# Javascript library for node-based objects and object relationships?

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I'm looking for a Javascript (preferably open source) library for displaying node-based objects and object relationships. Pretty basic stuff: show a node (which can be a simple box) and it's properties. Properties can have values. Sometimes, the value can be a relationship with another node (which creates a line between the two nodes).

Something like this:

http://www.datamation.com/img/2007/02/yahoo-pipes1.jpg

http://g.loquin.free.fr/udk/UnrealKismet%20Main_Sequence.Controls.jpg

http://www.brandspankingnew.net/img/headers/yahoo_pipes.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only wiring library i know is [WireIt](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/docs)

Answer (score 1):

d3.js works well for things like this.  You can see examples and learn more at http://mbostock.github.com/d3/.

Comment: This is a graph lib, not a graph wiring lib.

Comment: Your description talks about nodes with lines connecting them, d3.js can definitely do that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this library [Thejit](http://thejit.org/demos/)