# Displaying node trees

Tags: jquery, data-visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Javascript library for node-based objects and object relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10344832/javascript-library-for-node-based-objects-and-object-relationships)

Are there any Jquery plugins, or any solutions, for displaying a table of node relationships (a node has one parent and many children) given a table of this data?

Answer (score 0):

In what way would you like them to be displayed?

Here is a list of some plugins: http://www.webdesignbooth.com/15-great-jquery-plugins-for-better-table-manipulation/

I can show you this, which you can modify to suit your needs. What it is doing is recursing through an object graph. Note that the style to make this can be changed by editing the `function newDiv` code.

```
(function () {
     var jsonData = dataSentFromServer();
     var detailsElement = document.getElementById("Details");
     function newDiv(txt) {
         var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
         if (txt != undefined)
             createDiv.innerHTML = txt;
         return createDiv;
     }

     var depth = 1;
     (function ComposeGraph(obj, el) {
         var ElementArray = [];
         var ChildArray = [];
         $.each(obj, function (name, value) {
             if (!$.isArray(value)) {

                 var appender = newDiv(name + " __:__ " + value);
                 appender.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:" + 10 * depth + "px;");
                 if ($.isPlainObject(value)) {
                     appender.innerHTML = "<b>" + appender.innerHTML + "</b>";
                     depth++;
                     ComposeGraph(value, appender);
                     depth--;
                     ElementArray.push(el);
                     ChildArray.push(appender);
                 } else {
                     el.appendChild(appender);
                 }
             } else {
                 var appender = newDiv(name + " __:__ " + value);
                 appender.setAttribute("style", "margin-left:" + 10 * depth + "px;");
                 appender.innerHTML = "<b>" + appender.innerHTML + "</b>";
                 for (var i = 0, len = value.length; i < len; i++) {
                     depth++;
                     ComposeGraph(value[i], appender);
                     depth--;
                 }
                 ElementArray.push(el);
                 ChildArray.push(appender);
             }
         });
         for (var i = 0, len = ElementArray.length; i < len; i++) {
             ElementArray[i].appendChild(ChildArray[i]);
         }
     })(jsonData, detailsElement);
 })();
```